# urllib2.urlopen with pandas data

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, csv, google-maps-api-3

Hi,
I query the google places api with data from a outlook.csv export.
For example: `Fronäckerstr. 24","Sindelfingen","71063","Deutschland`

I read the data with pandas.

```
 pd.read_csv('/contacts.CSV')...
```

```
    place = urllib2.quote(street + '+' + city + '+' + postcode + '+' + country)
    url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' \
        + place \
        + google_key

    data = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
```

The url: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Fron%E4ckerstr.%2024%2BSindelfingen%2B71063%2BDeutschland&key=ABCD`


I always get :`HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`
I can't figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of parameter you are passing in the url is non-UTF-8 string, That is why you are getting 'HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request'.